# Form Button Won't submit in IE

Tags: javascript, button, internet-explorer-9

I have a form that just verifies the age of a user then submits it. The form works fine in FF, Safari & Chrome but not on IE 9 (i have only tested it on IE9 for now).

Here is the javascript

```
 <script type="text/ecmascript">
         function CalculateAge() {

        var a= document.getElementById("c").value;
         var d=document.getElementById("d").value;
         var m=document.getElementById("m").value;
         var y=document.getElementById("y").value;



         if (d != \'0\' && m != \'0\' && y != \'0\' ) {

            now = new Date()



            if (d) {

               /* born = new Date(y, d, m);

                age = Math.floor((now.getTime() - born.getTime()) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); */
                //from php spence

            /* now.getDate();//daty of month 1-30
            now.getFullYear();//four digits
            now.getMonth();//return month from 0-11
            */
            year_diff =now.getFullYear() - y;
            month_diff= (now.getMonth()+1)-m;
            day_diff=now.getDate()-d;

            if(month_diff<0){ 

            //--year_diff;
            y=year_diff-1;

            }

            else if((month_diff==0) && (day_diff<0)){ 


            //--year_diff;
            y=year_diff-1;

            }else{
            y=year_diff;
            }
            //alert(y);
            //alert(day_diff);
                //alert(year_diff);
                //alert(month_diff);
            //age=year_diff;
            b=a;
            h=new Number(b)+1;
            //alert("You are "+y+" years old and Your Country is "+document.getElementById("c").options[h].text);
            age=y;
            //alert(age);
                if(isNaN(age))

                {

                   alert(\'Input date is incorrect!\');

                }else if(a=="none"){
                alert("please select a country");
                }

                else

                {


                if(a==1||a==2||a==3||a==4||a==5||a==6||a==7||a==8||a==9||a==11||a==14||a==15||a==16||a==17||a==18||a==19||a==20||a==21||a==22||a==23||a==24||a==25||a==27||a==28||a==29||a==30||a==31||a==33||a==34||a==35||a==36||a==37||a==38||a==39||a==40||a==41||a==42||a==43||a==44||a==45||a==46||a==47||a==48||a==49||a==50||a==51||a==52||a==53||a==55||a==56||a==57||a==58||a==60||a==61||a==63||a==64||a==65||a==66||a==67||a==68||a==69||a==70||a==71||a==72||a==73||a==74||a==76||a==83||a==84||a==85||a==89||a==90||a==91||a==93||a==96||a==97||a==98||a==99||a==100||a==102||a==103||a==104||a==105||a==106||a==107||a==108||a==109||a==110||a==111||a==112||a==113||a==114||a==115||a==116||a==117||a==118||a==119||a==120||a==121||a==122||a==123||a==124||a==125||a==127||a==128||a==129||a==130||a==131||a==136||a==137||a==139||a==140||a==141||a==142||a==143||a==144||a==145||a==146||a==147||a==148||a==149||a==151||a==152||a==154||a==155||a==156||a==157||a==158||a==159||a==160||a==162||a==163||a==164||a==167||a==168||a==170||a==171||a==172||a==174||a==175||a==176||a==177||a==178||a==179||a==180||a==182||a==183||a==184||a==186||a==188||a==190||a==191||a==192||a==193||a==195||a==196||a==197){

if(age>=18){
    document.cookie ="chdg=testcookie; expires=3600; path=/tpfnew";
    window.location="index.php";

}
else{

window.location="reject.html";
}


}else if(a==32||a==92){

if(age>=19){
document.cookie ="chdg=testcookie; expires=3600; path=/tpfnew";
window.location="index.php";

}
else{

window.location="reject.html";
}

}
else if(a==86||a==138){
if(age>=20){
document.cookie = "chdg=hjko; expires=3600; path=/tpfnew";
window.location="index.php";

}
else{

window.location="reject.html";
}


}else if(a==187||a==185||a==161||a==150||a==135||a==133||a==79||a==75||a==12){
if(age>=21){
document.cookie ="chdg=testcookie; expires=3600; path=/tpfnew";
window.location="index.php";

}
else{

window.location="reject.html";
}
}

else if(a==78){
if(age>=25){
document.cookie ="chdg=testcookie; expires=3600; path=/tpfnew"; 
window.location="index.php";

}
else{

window.location="reject.html";
}

}
else if (a){window.location="reject2.html";}





        // window.location="welcome.php";
                    //alert(x+"is the "+age);
                    //alert(age);




            }}

        }else{alert("please select your Date of Birth.")}

    }




    </script>
```

thanx in advance
And here is the button input

```
<input type="button" onclick="CalculateAge();" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: _The form works fine in FF, Safari & Chrome_ - I don't think so...

Comment: what you meant by not working on IE does give you and error or its not doing any thing ?

Comment: It does not do anything at all when i click on the submit button, and the form is not meant to submit any info it's an age verification code that gives you access to the site after verifying that you are of the legal drinking age in your country.

Comment: @JoeyNg'ethe window.location = "index.php" won't submit the form. But that is not the only problem of your code.

Comment: @JoeyNg'eth please give use the html code for your qustion for id=c and d and m

Comment: @Andreas ok, then how I'm i supposed to do it then? by just making the above comments ain't helping me a lot mate

Comment: @JoeyNg'ethe You're saying the function works. But with the syntax errors in it, this can't be true. So you're either lying or haven't tested it at all. Have a look a shareef's anwser. It will fix one of your problems. For submitting the form have a look at [form.submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit).

Answer (score 0):

use it for one thing "submit" or function call.
You can do both if you call CalculateAge() function from button click and then perform submit action in that manually. Like

```
function CalculateAge(){
  //DO your Stuff here
  jQuery.post(<your URL> , jQuery('#formid).serialize(),function(data){
      jQuery('#your result div').html(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Rizstien, sorry i am not getting you. The form just verifies that you are of the legal drinking age and it just submit any information, instead it allows you to view the site. Something like a redirect. If you can include some sample code i would appreciate it mate.

Answer (score 0):

here is jsfiddle for you code with some modification in lines

[jsfiddle demo you code](http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/fMw7t/2/)

the line `if (d != \'0\' && m != \'0\' && y != \'0\' ) {` modified removed slashes 
the line `alert(\'Input date is incorrect!\');`       modified removed slashes

**because errors on these line see the link to see fix and it works without modifying any thing else**

i have tested them on firefox and ie8

Comment: thanx a lot mate but my problem was i hadn't put in values for a drop down selection i had in my html for selecting the age. So IE saw the fields as null. When i filled the fields with values it worked just fine on IE and FF, thanx

Comment: thanx mate, i should have posted the html in the first place and it would have saved us the time. But i'm glad i solved it :-) thanx once again

Comment: what was the problem could my answer be accepted as help or what ;)

Comment: definitely you helped me man.The problem was that i had a drop down to select your year of birth but i had not put values in it. So in FF it took the selected value as the value but in IE it seemed not to do that. So putting in values did the trick, something like;

    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select year</option>
    <option value="1950">1950</option>
    <option value="1951">1951</option>
    <option value="1952">1952</option>
    <option value="1953">1953</option>
    <option value="1954">1954</option> e.t.c